# Import only DCIM from Android phone

Tags: windows-7, android, import, dcim

I tried to import photos and videos captured with a Nexus mobile phone. The photos and videos are stored in the DCIM folder. I have many more images on the mobile phone, which I do not want to import, for example MP3 album art images or images from other applications but the camera stored in many different directories out of the DCIM folder. Windows 7 imports all those images. Now I have music covers in my holiday images.

How to tell Windows 7 to import only the DCIM folder and no other folder?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and haven't found a way to do it directly with Windows 7.  I imagine there is other software that will "import" from a specific folder, but I haven't looked extensively.  I have worked around the issue by copying my DCIM folder to a USB flash drive, then import the images from the flash drive (using Windows 7 import).

Answer (score 0):

On your phone, where you see the USB connection, select "Transferring images". This will only allow access to DCIM and Pictures.